# Selenium + Python expect specific already found element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'd like to use expect on an object already located but I'm getting an error.
I am able to locate the parent only before it is clicked -- afterwards it mutates into "one-of-many-alike" input elements and only way to distinguish it is "value" property (not attribute thus cannot be accessed from XPath).

My code is (something like):

```
parent_element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div/div/input[position()=10]/div")
parent_element.click()  # After this I cannot locate parent_element any more
child_element = WebDriverWait(self.driver,3).until(
    expect.element_to_be_clickable(
        parent_element.find_element_by_xpath("./div")
    )
)
child_element.click()
```

Which leads to:

```
TypeError: find_element() argument after * must be an iterable, not function
```

Comment: `parent_element.find_element_by_xpath("./div")`  is it  right code `('./div')` ? maybe `('//div')`

Comment: "./div" as I wish to find a subelement of context node "parent_element"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this line:

```
child_element = WebDriverWait(parent_element, 3).until(
    expect.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "./div")))
```

Note that `element_to_be_clickable()` should receive tuple of `"by"` and `"value"` as the only argument, but not WebElement

P.S. I assume that `expect` is `ExpectedConditions`

Comment: Yes, expect is ExpectedConditions.
Thanks!